# Свернуть/Развернуть блок текста

Tags: php

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как сделать переключатель такой.Скрин залиит не могу,репутация не позволяет,тогда залью часть кода.Тоесть по нажатию на ссылку показать список вещей,блок который формирует второй форич должен быть развернут! У меня была мысль что надо пробежаться в цикле по каждой строке который формирует форич,и развернуть ее,правильно мыслю? если нет подскажите как сделать!

```
foreach($matches as $category => $things){
        $number = 0;
        $total = 0;
        $total_pnd = 0;

        echo "<table align = 'center' class = 'info'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan ='3'>$category</th>
                </tr>";
        echo "<tr>
                  <td colspan='3'>

                            <a href='javascript:showList()' style='text-decoration:none;'>
                                <img src='img/show.gif' style='margin-right:5px;'>Показать список вещей</img>
                            </a>

                  </td>
              </tr>";

        foreach($things as $thing){
            $number ++;
            $total += $thing['quantity'];
            $total_pnd += ($thing['value']*$thing['quantity']);

            echo "<tr><td align = 'center' width = '30'>$number</td><td class = $thing[quality]>";
                switch($thing['category']){
                    case "Право на дружбу": $tr = "<b>$thing[title]&nbsp[$thing[value]]&nbsp</b>";break;
                    case "Чарки" : $tr = "<b>$thing[title]&nbsp[$thing[level]]&nbsp</b>";break;
                    default : $tr = "<b>$thing[title]&nbsp</b>";
                }

            echo $tr;
            echo "<small><span><b class = $thing[quality]>&nbsp$thing[quality]&nbsp</b></span></small></td>
                  <td align = 'center' width = '30'>$thing[quantity]</td></tr>";
            }

                switch($thing['category']){
                    case "Право на дружбу": $tr_total = "<tr class='total'><td colspan='2'>Всего ПНД</td><td>$total_pnd</td></tr>";break;
                    case "Ненадеваемые вещи ТН": $tr_total = "<tr class='total'><td colspan='2'>Всего</td><td>$total</td></tr>";break;
                }
            echo $tr_total;
        echo "</table></br>";
    }
```

Comment: Народ подскажите идею, пожалуйста!

Comment: представьте, что вы ничего не знаете о вашем проекте и перечитайте вопрос ещё раз.